# php/javascript drawing tool

Tags: php

I can use GD or something to draw user-selected shapes by writing some lines of code, but is there a library that is already taking care of it?

There are just 4-5 shapes that a user can select and text needs to be placed too.

Comment: Maybe you are searching for a Javascript solution? This "selection" and "text placing" need to be *interactive*? If yes, the only solution is Javascript, and if so, you should edit your question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want a library that does the same thing as GD? Why not just use GD?

Comment: @Juhana GD is more for drawing behind the scene. I want the user to draw and just have a final image to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want I think you want (to draw in browser without using server side scripting) check this article out, perhaps you will find what you need:

[10-jquery-drawing-plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-drawing-plugins/)

Enjoy!